# Ubuntu failed to boot (windows dual boot) on Gigabyte Brix BXBT 1900

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

I tried to install Ubuntu 16.04 (dual boot Windows 10) on a Gigabyte Brix BXBT 1900. Windows 10 runs fine on this machine. I booted ubuntu from a live USB and everything went fine till the installation finished. After the installation, the pc hung up on boot and failed to load Grub. I couldn't even boot to windows because of this.

I've also updated the BIOS for this machine following this instruction on;

https://www.gigabytenordic.com/update-bios-gigabyte-brix/

using the F8 BIOS upgrade from Gigabyte website.

I've tried installing Kubuntu, Lubuntu and Manjaro too but they all failed to boot after the installation. I have to choose DualBoot option since I still need windows for some works.

So, for those who have any experience in running Ubuntu on this machine, please share it here. I really want to run ubuntu on it.

Thanks.

### Update- Sept 16, 2016

I read this post on an LinuxMint forum;
https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=205842
It seems like we have the same problem and I found no solution.

Is it really impossible to run Ubuntu (or other linux distros) in this machine?

Comment: have you tried using live cd?... means does your pc boot up with a live cd?

Comment: Yes, everything is fine with the live cd. Even the installation went ok. Ubuntu Live Cd even managed to format a partition to ext4 (which is inaccessible in windows by default). It's just that I can't see the dual boot menu after doing initial restart  after installation. Just a blank screen.

Comment: I decided to wipe out Windows partition on this device and fresh install Ubuntu on it (no dual boot this time ). Everything runs well so far except for occasional freezing that occurs in this machine (other users of this machine also experience this).